# Lambda triggering error when executed

Tags: init-file

I'm setting up a mechanism that allows me to conveniently specify minor modes in a list that should not take up space in the modeline.

At the bottom of the following code snippet, this list is iterated and, for each mode, a hook is setup which, when invoked should call `(diminish 'mode)`.  I'm getting an error when the hook is invoked, however, and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong here.

I went with a lambda hook function as a way of circumventing lexical binding constraints.

```el
(setq my/diminished-modes '(projectile-mode ivy-mode eldoc-mode auto-fill-mode yas-minor-mode))    

(defun add-suffix-to-symbol (sym suffix)
  "Add a suffix to a symbol name."
  (intern (concatenate 'string "" (symbol-name sym) suffix)))

;; This fails with the following error:
;; Symbol’s value as variable is void: mode
(dolist (mode my/diminished-modes)
  (add-hook (add-suffix-to-symbol mode "-hook")
            `(lambda () (diminish ',mode))))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: My guess is that you've left bad lambdas from earlier attempts in those hooks.  Putting lambda functions in hook variables is generally a bad idea, and that's one of the reasons why.

Comment: Maybe try `...(diminish (quote ,mode)))))` ? What does `diminish` look like? Does it take a symbol as argument?

Comment: Apologies for misusing the tags. I'm getting the error when I start a new Emacs session so definitely nothing to do with earlier attempts. I thought that `mode` gets injected into the lambda and, if so, no error should be triggered?

Comment: Tangentially, you might find https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes simpler than doing this.

Comment: Strangely, `(diminish (quote ,mode))` works and no error is thrown. Now that I've got that to work, will be looking into DelightedModes as it seems to do what I need and more. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @phils The Delight package doesn't seem to work in Emacs 28.0.50 .

Comment: @miguelg It works for me on a recent build, so maybe it's just a misconfiguration?  Feel free to ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to `(quote ,mode)` rather than `',mode`.  Unsure why.

```lisp
(setq my/diminished-modes '(projectile-mode ivy-mode eldoc-mode auto-fill-mode yas-minor-mode))
    
(dolist (mode my/diminished-modes)
  (add-hook (add-suffix-to-symbol mode "-hook")
            `(lambda () (diminish (quote ,mode)))))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem whereby `',mode` and `(quote ,mode)` behave differently.  They both do the same thing for me (in 27.2 and in my build of 28).